# As the mother of a child or As a mother of a child

Tags: articles, definite-articles

May I know which one of these is the correct answer.

1. As the mother of a child
2. As a mother of a child

I have seen both phrases used. However, a child only has one mother, therefore I believe the phrase "As the mother of a child " is correct. However, I have seen both phrases used in many newspaper articles. May I know the difference?

Similarly, these two phrases are also used. However, a football club only has one manager. Therefore, why do people use the second phrase.

1. He is the manager of a football club.
2. He is a manager of a football club.

Comment: It depends on the context of the utterance.

Comment: It depends on context and who is speaking.

Answer (score 1):

Either can be used correctly.

**1.** As ***the*** mother of a child: implies a specific relationship to the object. She is "the" mother of "that" child (or whichever child is being referenced or talked about in the context of the conversation).

**2.** As ***a*** mother of a child: implies that she is a mother of a child, with no specific relationship to the object. She is "a" mother of "some" child.

Tom22 was right in his comments but in spoken or written English the difference is so subtle that either of these are correct.

Comment: I got this phrase from an article "as the mother of a 17-year-old", why is "the" used instead "a", they are talking about some "17-year-old". If someone asks me about my occupation. Do I say "I am the/a manager of a post office".

Comment: Either option at the end of your comment is acceptable. You can say "I am the manager of a post office" or "I am a manager of a post office". The difference is subtle. But the second one implies there could be other managers, since you are not "the" manager at a post office, just "a" manager. Does that help understand?

Comment: Oh and as for the first part of your comment, the article could have written it either way. Using "a" in that case would have been acceptable. They just chose to use "the".

Comment: "the post office" is a bit of a special case as there is one 'brand' of post office.  I'm not so sure I agree with Kace36 in general though.  If you were to say "I am the manager of the football club" and the person hearing didn't know Which football club, it would be confusing to them ... they would wonder if they were suppose to know which one  etc... it would not be a good way to describe your career role generally. My 2cents

Comment: Oh, let me be clear. I agree with @Tom22 that it's not the best way to go unless you are stating a specific place or thing you are managing. I just meant to say they are both grammatically correct. There is nothing grammatically wrong with either. But, yes, I agree. You would want to say "I am the manager of the Pizza Hut" vs "I am the manager of the pizza place". Unless the person knew what pizza place you were talking about. Or maybe if it were the only one in town.

Comment: Let me add though that you could say (regarding my comment above): "I am the manager of "a" pizza place". And once again this would tend to indicate you are the only manager as opposed to if you said, "I am "a" manager of "a" pizza place". This would tend to indicate there might be more managers. You wouldn't want to say "the" pizza place unless someone knew which place you were talking about. I hope this helps.

Comment: A person has only one biological mother, but a person can have more than one mother during a lifetime (or even at the same time, depending the sense of the word). This is another way in which "*a*" can be different from "*the*".

Comment: 'As the mother of a child' might just pass muster, used for emphasis, but 'As a mother of a child' sounds faintly ridiculous. What else can a lady be a literal mother of?

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of what you consider to be the noun phrase that the article is associated with.

- If it's "mother", then your interpretation holds. The child has only one mother, so use "the".
- If it's "mother of a child", then your interpretation doesn't hold. There are lots of people who are mothers of children, and the expression refers to only one of them. In this case, use "a".

The logic regarding the manager example follows the same pattern.

Answer (score 0):

**The** is used with nouns that are (i) defined or indicated within the clause or elsewhere, or (ii) are known to both the speaker and listener:

**The** cat **that is on the wall** is big. / Look! [points] **The** bird is attacking **the** cat.

**The** moon is bright. (Everyone is aware of the moon.)

**A/an** [noun] ~ an/one example of [a class noun]

**A** cat is a good pet - **An example of the thing that we call** "cat" is one example of good pet.

**As the mother of a child** - the use of **the** is justified by the noun "mother" being defined by "of a child". In this the speaker is specifying/defining herself.

**As a mother of a child** - As one example of a mother, who happens to have a child. In this the speaker is saying that she is a typical example of the class of "mothers" - it is therefore generalised.